How can photons be absorbed by matter, without causing ionization or new photons?
Let's say we have a gas, of argon atoms for example. We raise the temperature of the gas to 20,000K. Some atoms collide with enough energy that the atoms ionize, into free electrons and ions.
So, now we have a plasma, comprising a mixture of neutral atoms, free electrons, and ions.
Now, let's say we cool down the plasma, to 300K for example. We can imagine that at a macroscopic level, the ions and free electrons will recombine, and we will no longer have a plasma. But what happens concretely?
When a free electron and an ion recombine, a photon will be released, e.g. How can a free electron and an ion in a plasma recombine without violating conservation of energy and momentum?  The ionization energy of argon is 16eV, corresponding to UV light of around 70nm.
The UV photon now moves through the plasma. Somehow we'd expect this is going to get converted ultimately to thermal energy - kinetic energy - but how?
If the UV photon hits a neutral argon atom, it will ionize that atom I think? So, we'll just have an endless cycle of ionization => recombination + photon => ionization => etc.?
So, how does the UV photon get converted into thermal energy? I saw there is Compton scattering, which can reduce the energy of a photon. Maybe something like that?

There are multiple factors here. Generally, the recombination can lead to high-energy photons that will be able to ionize again. However, there are processes that will not allow for this. The first possibility is that of multi-particle scattering where the energy is transferred to kinetic energy of a different ion or a change in its internal energy structure. The second is that though the ionization energy is high on recombination there is no guarantee that the atom will be in its ground state. I.e. the absorbed electron can be excited and then fall to ground state in a second step.

Alright. So multi-particle scattering is essentially the symmetric reverse of two neutral atoms colliding then ionizing, so that makes total sense to me. In the latter case, although this will lead to photons of lower energy, the energy will be still being stored as 'photons' rather than 'thermal' 'ke'. How will the photon energy end up becoming thermal ke?

(Note: I say 'being stored as photons', since presumably when the electron does fall to ground state in a second step, that will emit a new photon?)

Oh.. maybe what happens is that the photons gradually convert to lower and lower energy photons, until they are in the IR range, and can be absorbed as thermal vibrations?

Oh, well, except that argon is monatomic, and does not allow vibrational or rotational states, so cannot absorb the IR as thermal energy?

oh, maybe 'collisional de-excitation', where an excited atom collides with another atom, and converts the excitational energy into KE of the colliding atoms, during the collision?

I think your last comment should be the answer. And of course, if you have molecules vibration and rotation modes also work as you mentioned. Maybe as a ad-on, we do not yet fully understand what these different progress actually contribute in mixtures (especially at low density but high energy e.g. in remnants of supernovae etc)

Cool. Looks like there is also Raman Scattering, where the photon imparts some kinetic energy to the argon atom, and reduces its own energy (ie increases its wavelength).

Oh... here's a guess at what happens: when the photon strikes an ion, since the second ionization energy is generally higher than first ionization energy, so the ionization energy is used to raise the next electron to a higher energy level. And the energy level is higher than ionization level because now the ion is charged, and attracts the electron more strongly. How does that sound?

Ok, here's my current idea of what happens:

the energy to remove a second electron from an atom (the "second ionization energy") is higher than the energy to remove the first (the "first ionization energy")

This is because once one electron is removed, the ion is now charged, and more strongly attracts the remaining electrons


when a photon hits an ion, then the photon energy is not sufficient to ionize the ion further
so the "outermost" electron in the ion is not ionized, but is raised in energy, to some higher level of $n$, but less than $\infty$ ($n = \infty$ would be ionization, I believe?)

Now, the excited ion could decay by creating a new photon. However, that would recreate our original photon, so we ignore this. So, moving on:

the excited ion strikes another particles, e.g. another ion, or a neutral atom
on the collision, some or all of the excitation energy is converted into kinetic energy of the particle that was struck ("Raman Scattering")

This is for sure not the only path for a photon at ionization energy to become thermal or kinetic energy. But it's one path. Which answers the question of how "can".
